# Is it correct to use services to communicate between angular components?

Tags: angular, angular-services

Is it correct to use **services to communicate between angular components**?
If I have a component which opens a modal

```
this.taskService.activeTask = this.currentTask;
this.tagSelectModalRef = this.modalService.show(TagSelectorComponent, {});
```

Is it correct to "pass" the element that the modal has to work with via a service as in the example?

If it were to components that visualize side by side where the click in one of them affect the other component, will it also be correct?

Thanks,
Enric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use a service to communicate between components. It's clearly documented in the official angular documentaion in the [component interaction section](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

Comment: Thank you. I have to read them carefully. I have done a course of Angular and I still need to settle some concepts.

Comment: Best thing is to follow the official angular documentaion. Take your time and read each and every concept in the documentation. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I have personally done what you are trying to do in the past by creating 2 separate components. I find that this is a cleaner implementation assuming all you're doing in that service is sharing data. But technically there is nothing wrong with using a service if you do want to go that route. If you were doing operations on that data that were independent of both the modal and the component and were looking to run them separately and independent of the component or modal I would lean more towards using a service.

*Concept of using 2 components explained below:*

So you'll have your component you already have, but convert the modal into your second component.

Anything that needs to be shared between the two components can then be done by using `@Input`, `@ViewChild`, and `@Output`. Basically, anything you need passed down from your top level component you would use an `@Input` in the modal component. Anything you need to notify the top level component of from the modal, depending on what you're trying to pass back up the tree or what behaviors you’re looking to trigger you could use either an `@Output` and an `EventEmitter` from the `@angular/core` imports in the modal component, or you could use `@ViewChild` in the top level component.

Comment: In fact, I already created 2 components: one for the modal, as it is used in 2 different places. But I was not able to pass data with the \@Input and \@Output

Comment: Were you receiving an error when doing this or was the data just not received. I could help you if you had a stackblitz replicating the issue. Although, like I said if the service works there’s not necessarily anything wrong with that either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use services to communicate between sibling components. If you need to communicate parent with children or children with parent use @input and @output